# How to make an SVG embedded inline in HTML load its xlink:href dependencies?

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, gnuplot, xlink

I have SVG files that I need to embed inline in an HTML file (using the HTML5 `<svg>` tag).  Those SVG files have a JavaScript dependency, which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    xlink:href="http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_4.6/gnuplot_svg.js">
</script>
```

Here is a [standalone SVG](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_4.6/simple.1.svg) image with that script dependency.  To activate the JavaScript, you can click on the image, and then there's a box that follows your cursor telling you your (x,y) coordinates.

However, [here is the same image](http://jsbin.com/lakowaneko/1/edit?html,output) embedded directly into an HTML document.  According to the web inspector, the browser never even tries to load the JavaScript dependency.  When you click and move your cursor around the image, the console fills up with a bunch of reference errors.

How do you make the embedded version load its JavaScript and function like the standalone version?

Comment: Your JS Bin shows JS errors in console.

Comment: @CBroe Indeed.  It says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: gnuplot_svg is not defined."  That variable, *gnuplot_svg*, is defined in the JavaScript file that's not being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the document you link uses a self closing `<script>` and that does not work (unsure if this is a bug in browsers or not).

The code as you write it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    xlink:href="http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_4.6/gnuplot_svg.js">
</script>
```

will at least load the script, but then the script assumes the document's root element is an `<svg>` element (it uses getScreenCTM) and in an HTML document the root element will be an `<html>` element.

Maybe it won't help you, but you need a different version of the script.

Comment: Note that using self closing tags inside svg elements is supposed to work, because the contents of the svg element should be parsed using the xml parser rather than the html one.

Comment: Good observation about the closing script tag.  It's unfortunate that the script still doesn't work because of the document root, but I'll accept the post since it answers the question about loading the JavaScript element.

Comment: Mr Lister, thanks for fixing the syntax of the response!